# Undefined index:trying to make a 'details' page with $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am making a project for one course and I need to make a prototype of a movie website with all the artists and movies. I need to display the results of the search by the name of the artist and to make a link to a page with more details about the artist. 
Part of code for search page:

```
        elseif ($method=='artist')
    { 
      $x=0;
      $query = "SELECT artistId, image, firstname,lastname,dateOfBirth,otherInfo FROM $artists WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE '%$kword%' OR lastname LIKE '%$kword%' or firstname like '%$kword%'";
      mysqli_select_db($connect, $mydb);
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

      if($result)

        {
            print '<table >';
            while  ($sqlRow=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
            {
            $x++;
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td rowspan=\"3\" id=\"image\">";
                echo '<img src="' . $sqlRow['image'] . '" alt="alt">';
                echo"</td>";
                echo "<td id=\"title\"><strong><a href=artist_details.php?id=".$sqlRow['artistId'].">".$sqlRow['firstname']." ".$sqlRow['lastname']."</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td id=\"date\"><strong>".$sqlRow['dateOfBirth']."</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td id=\"desc\">".$sqlRow['otherInfo']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            print '</table>';
            if ($x==0)
            {
            echo "<h4>";
            echo "No matches found";
            echo "</h4>";
            }
        }

    }
```

The code for the details page:

```
$query = "SELECT artistId, image, firstname,lastname,dateOfBirth,otherInfo FROM $artists WHERE artistId=".$_GET['artistId'];
      mysqli_select_db($connect, $mydb);
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

      if($result)

        {
            print '<table >';
            while  ($sqlRow=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
            {
            $x++;
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td rowspan=\"3\" id=\"image\">";
                echo '<img src="' . $sqlRow['image'] . '" alt="alt">';
                echo"</td>";
                echo "<td id=\"title\"><strong><a href=\"artist_detail.php?id=".$sqlRow['artistId']."\">".$sqlRow['firstname']." ".$sqlRow['lastname']."</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td id=\"date\"><strong>".$sqlRow['dateOfBirth']."</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td id=\"desc\">".$sqlRow['otherInfo']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            print '</table>';
            }
```

Every time I get the same error:Undefined index: artistId.
I would be really grateful for your help! :)

Comment: Are you passing in `artistId=<something>` in the URL? And are you aware that your code is open to an SQL injection attack?

Comment: `artistId` is not the same as `artistd

Comment: anrewsi, I know that GET is not secure but I dont quite know any other solution since I am a beginner in PHP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to set the artistId to a _GET value of

```
id
```

in

```
echo "<td id=\"title\"><strong><a href=\"artist_detail.php?id=".$sqlRow['artistId']."\">".$sqlRow['firstname']." ".$sqlRow['lastname']."</strong></td>";
```

but you look up

```
$_GET['artistId']
```

Without having understood your code entirely this might help:

```
echo "<td id=\"title\"><strong><a href=\"artist_detail.php?artistId=".$sqlRow['artistId']."\">".$sqlRow['firstname']." ".$sqlRow['lastname']."</strong></td>";
```

Comment: Be sure to select check this answer as your accepted answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the **`isset`** construct before assigning variables from a foreign value say `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

You need to check like this..

```
if(isset($_GET['artistId']))
{
$artistId = $_GET['artistId']; // filter this variable before passing directly to your SQL query, else you will be under the SQL Injection Scanner !
//do your query here
}
else
{
echo "Artist Id was not passed";
}
```

First check whether your URL is passing the `artistId` to your details page. for instance.. `http://yourpage.com/artistDetail.php?artistId=3403`

Comment: it is passing the value to the URL but still gives me an undefined index

Comment: There is no way you would get an undefined index error if you had implemented the `isset` construct.